# Zend_Session where is the cookie?

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, session-cookies

i'm using Zend_Session::start() on each request because I need to save the values ​​between the various requests (for example user and password for re-use it in future access to db).

I would like to know if the cookie is created when i use Zend_Session::start(), and most importantly where I can see the path where is stored (both server and client).

I read that in fact the use of sessions involves the creation of a cookie but I'm not sure if the same is true with the Zend_Session seen that there is also Zend_Http_Cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend_Session extends the standard PHP session functionality, so yes starting a session sets a cookie. Where the session data is stored depends on your configuration, by default the data is stored in files, the location of which is controlled by the config value `session.save_path`.

You wouldn't typically store the password in the session - once a user has been authenticated you might store just the username in the session for later access. Zend_Auth will handle all of this for you if you are using that component.

Forget about Zend_Http_Cookie, it has nothing to do with user cookies.

Comment: thanks!! if i save only username into a session, where can i take password to do a connect on db?

Comment: The idea is that you store the username only once the user has been authenticated (i.e. they are logged in). Then on subsequent requests you can trust that the username in the session belongs to the current user, so you don't need the password.

Comment: ok but in my web application, on a subsequent requests i need to call a metod i5_connect($user,$pwd) to get data from DB2. where i don't need the password?

Comment: Does that method load data for the current user that your application uses? Or something else?

Comment: this method is the same of mysq_connect() but i'm using this to connect to DB2 on ibmI. i need to create the connection (i prefer create a connection for every user with his credential)

Comment: Well, that's a new one on me. Normally your application only has one set of db details that are stored in a config file somewhere. If you are connecting with user-specific details then yes that does sound like it's worth storing in the session.

Comment: i can also use always the same user and pwd to access into db and stor it into my config.ini do you think that is more efficent in this way?? or is better use different user and save it into session? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All sessions need some way for the client to authenticate against.

Meaning, the server will give the client a key (or a session ID), usually in the form of a cookie, and link (internally, on the server-side) the session variables to that ID.

When the client sends a request, it also sends the session ID with the cookies, which allows the server to fetch the variables associated with that ID, and allow use by the programmer.

The path of the cookies changes per browser.

That means that the client **only has the ID**, the client does not know what is in the session variables, he cannot see them.

---

Now I don't know Zend very well, but I assume that `Zend_Session` is for sessions, while `Zend_Http_Cookie` is for an actual cookie (where the value of the variable itself is stored in the cookie). Do not store critical information in a cookie, as it is easily readable and changable.

Answer (score 2):

From [`Zend_Session` documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.introduction.html):

> Zend_Session uses the normal PHP ext/session functions internally, all the familiar configuration options and settings apply (see http://www.php.net/session)

You may also configure some behaviors of `Zend_Session` using `Zend_Session::setOptions()`:

```
Zend_Session::setOptions(array(
  'use_only_cookies' => 'on',
  'remember_me_seconds' => 864000
));
```

See also [`Zend_Session` Advanced Usage](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.advanced_usage.html)